# How can I prove which differential form is either closed or exact?

Tags: differential-geometry

We have three differential forms:

1. $\omega = yzdx + xzdy + xydz$
2. $\omega = xdx + x^2y^2dy + yzdz$
3. $\omega  = 2xy^2 \: dx \wedge dy + z\: dy \wedge dz$

We say, that a differential form is **closed**, if $d \omega = 0$

We say, that a differential form is **exact**, if there exists another differential form $\tau$ such that $d\tau = \omega$

---

Now my question is: How can we actually calculate $d\omega$?

I only know the formula for $\omega = \alpha dx + \beta dy$:

$$d\omega = (\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}) dx \wedge dy - \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z} dx \wedge dz - \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z} dy \wedge dz$$

But here, we actually have $\omega = \alpha dx + \beta dy + \gamma dz$ in the first two ones, and $\omega = \alpha dx \wedge dy + \beta dx \wedge dz + \gamma dy \wedge dz$ in the third one.

So what is the formula for $d\omega$ for these kinds of $\omega$?

---

Also, how can I find this "another differential form $\tau$"?

Comment: Use $d(\alpha\wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha \wedge d\beta$. For exactness, since you seem to consider differential forms on $\Bbb R^3$, you can invoke [Poincaré's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma).

Comment: We haven't done Poincare's Lemma in our lectures. Also, I don't see it how to use the formula you've given me now here. I mean, we have $d\omega = d (\alpha dx \wedge dy + ....) = d (\alpha dx \wedge dy) + d (...) + d(...)$, so if we concentrate only on $d(\alpha dx \wedge dy)$, this would mean what exactly? As $\alpha$ is not a coefficient?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differential forms. e.g, $d(z dx \wedge dy) = d(zdx) \wedge dy - zdx \wedge d(dy)$ since $zdx$ is of degree $1$. Compute separately $d(zdx)$ and $d(dy)$ then take the wedge product. You also have to use $d(f\alpha) = df \wedge d\alpha + f d\alpha$ for a smooth function $f$ and a differential form $\alpha$.

Comment: A differential form on $ \mathbb R ^ n $, if it's defined everywhere and differentiable, is exact if and only if it is closed.  (This is Poincaré's Lemma.)  So unless you need to explicitly find $ \tau $, you're just checking whether these are closed.